# Автодополнение функций в Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы в ST2 могли автодополняться не только нативные, но и пользовательские функции (PHP)? Он подставляет только имена, а аргументы нет, и подсказку не выводит, как для нативных функций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автодополнение в ST2 работают несколько по другому: при наборе текста всплывающая подсказка срабатывает на уже добавленный в исходный код текст. Это не тот автокомплит, что например в   WebStorm или других  IDE.

Comment: В смысле? Вот я пишу `prin`, выпадает список, там выделено первым `print_r`, я жму Enter, и в итоге пишется `print_r(expression)`, то есть он всю сигнатуру написал за меня.  
А если я так делаю со своей функцией, то он только название пишет, без аргументов.

Comment: В смысле я понимаю, что он дописывает слова, которые есть в текущем файле (есть ещщё плагин для заинклюженных файлов), но ведь тут он дописывает.  
Что, совсем это никак не сделать? :-(

Comment: Я имею в виду то, что по умолчанию ST2 понятия не имеет о функциях и их сигнатуре в PHP. Он просто помогает вам вводить тот текст, что был написан ранее. Если мое утверждение не верно, значит скорее всего вы используете плагины.

Comment: Необходимо устанавливать плагины, если таковые вообще существуют. Поищите их на Github.

Comment: Я написал выше, как он себя ведёт. Он же дописывает сигнатуры PHP. Без всяких сторонных плагинов (в смысле я не ставил их). Ну у него там есть, правда, PHP папка в дополнениях, как и для многих других языков. Сейчас гляну.

Comment: Мой совет все таки не пользоваться продвинутым автокомплитом. Так лучше запоминается код который вы пишите. А для сигнатур всегда есть документация.

Comment: @andreycrane, да, мне нормально и так, просто сейчас вот сижу думаю уже долго - нужно ли мне PhpDoc писать перед каждой функцией? Я думал, что если буду писать, то он мне подсказывать удобно будет по нему, ан нет.